# Toilet wont flush completely

Tags: bathroom

My toilet won't flush - it does what I call water exchange. I ran a hose down vent stack and it rinsed out as it should. Cleared all holes in bowl, put a rock in the tank. When it flushes, it fills bowl just below 3/4" of coming up and over bowl. It swirls but with little force. As tank begins to fill, bowl continues to fill.

I have always thought water level in toilet bowel was too high. It will flush when I use a bucket of water.

Side note: my house is set with a grinder and pump to get to city sewer - very slight slope, not noticeable. Checked flapper.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What do you mean by "water exchange"? Why did you put a rock in the tank, and what happened?

Comment: Lol My terlet did this. I used a short auger and was able to pull out about 100 qtips.... Have kids they said, its fun they said....

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is a clog in your line.  Is there anything stuck in the hole that jets out water (in the front, below waterline.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing the rock if it interferes with the water flow. 
Then I would check the rubber seal in the flushing mechanism, sometimes it folds also interfering with the water flow.